# Unity bounce and move

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game similar to golf. My situation is this:

I have colliders like martinellas, so their behavior is to bounce ball and keep the same amount of speed.

Well, since I added some abilities, one ability is that my ball transforms into a wheel and goes only in forward direction at higher speed. When it collides with martinellas, it should bounce by Y axis only (in air) and stop movement as well. I managed to do it by freezing the positions.

Looks good for now, but I have a problem: when the ball touches the ground, it collides again, because it goes to the first position of collision. It makes sense.

Now, I need help on how to only bounce in the air, and little bit backwards, so it doesn't collide again (without freezing the positions, I guess).

So, here I added a picture to understand it easier.

[image]

1st and 2nd scenario works now.

Now I need the 4th scenario.

The 3rd scenario shows how the ball is dropping by default: it drops down to position of ball in 2nd scenario, which makes collision again. I need the ball to drop down by changed direction, not much, only a little bit to evade the collision.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to checkout [ask]. It'll help you ask good questions that will allow us to spend less time trying to figure out the question, and more time figuring out the answer to the question! Also, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate between y-axis between fixed position.

```
Vector3 interpolatedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(
new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z),
new Vector3(transform.position.x, 5, transform.position.z), Time.deltaTime * 5);

transform.position = interpolatedPosition;
```

Comment: Okay, now without freezing Im getting what I needed thank you! Now one more thing, can I somehow move my ball while bounced a bit backwards, so its not droping to the collision again.

Comment: Do you want it to move on keypress?

Comment: I added a picture for easier understanding, no not on a key press, once key is pressed forced is added, bouncing and everything else should be automatically..lets say when its collided it should change x position by small ammount to evade collision with martinell once again on drop.

Comment: Ok ok you can add rigidbody to you game object or you need to create whole physics engine